# David is not very fit. He does not do any sport. VS David is not very fit. He is not doing any sport

Tags: grammar, present-continuous, present-simple

> David is not very fit. He does not do any sport.

VS

> David is not very fit. He is not doing any sport.

Which is grammatically correct? What is the difference in meaning?

Comment: They are both grammatically correct. What do you think the meaning of each is?

Comment: I thought that the first one was quite correct. But the second one might lack casual link between to sentences. David is not very fit. He has not been doing any sport. This one sounds better for me.

Comment: The difference between *He **hasn't been doing** any sport* and *He isn't doing any sport* is that the ***past perfect*** progressive form tends to imply ***until now***. Which would make it more suitable if you were at the side of the school football pitch discussing why *your* son isn't playing very well compared to the others - at which time he obviously ***is*** "doing sport", but that's a new situation that's only just changed.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, "hasn't been doing" is present perfect progressive. And according to grammarly.com "The present perfect continuous tense (also known as the present perfect progressive tense) shows that something started in the past and is continuing at the present time." That's why I thought it might  be suitable in aforementioned situation if we imply that David used to do some sport in the past.

Comment: Why didn't you point out in the question that you *thought [Present Perfect Progressive] might ... imply that David used to do some sport in the past*. That's absolutely true, but Present Perfect Progressive would be *He **has not been doing** any sport.* Your example #2 is just Present Progressive (it's not a "perfect" verb form). If you'd explained what you thought you knew (effectively, and ***why*** you thought that), it would have been easier to explain where you'd gone wrong.

Comment: I am sorry for making it way harder than it should be. The reason I wrote the post is that I had a discussion with some random person on whether we can change present simple to present continuous in the second sentence. When I asked her for the reason for that change, she said that (according to her point of view) David's not doing any sport was temporary. Like he probably was into sports in the past and may be doing sports in the future. We just don't know. Pointing out that we have no reasons for such speculations I suggested that present perfect progr. would be a better choise in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Both verb forms *(**to do, to be doing**)* are syntactically fine, but most native speakers<sup>1</sup> would normally assume a difference in meaning...

> 1: *He **does not do** any sport*
>    Quite possibly he *never* engaged in sporting activities. The speaker is probably identifying what he sees as a ***permanent characteristic*** of the subject (he's just not ["the sporting type"](https://www.moodscope.com/blog/not-the-sporting-type)).
>
> 2: *He **is not doing** any sport*
>    The progressive verb form strongly implies a ***temporary situation***. Although he's not *currently* engaged in sports, he used to and/or perhaps *will be* doing so at other times.

---

<sup>1</sup> I believe speakers of "Indian English" do not make this distinction, and are in fact likely to use the continuous verb form (#2) for both senses. Which is fine when interacting with other IE speakers, but such "overuse" of continuous verb forms will usually be noticed by "mainstream" Anglophones.